# Make interpolation bicubic work in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

Any javascript/jquery workaround to make css -ms-interpolation-mode bicubic image work in ie9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530822.aspx this property is obsolete in IE 9. In other words, interpolation is always bicubic for stretched images in IE 9; it's never a nearest-neighbor algorithm.

If you use a CSS property like `filter` though, good luck.

Comment: yes i aware that not supported anymore. My question is any workaround/hack ? can use elaborate how to use filter to achieve similar result?

Comment: It's not needed any more. It's like all images have `-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic` set for them. So you don't have to implement a workaround, because that's the normal behavior now.

Comment: i tested, it does not applied that by default. do you have any reference article explains on this.. from my test, resized image look terrible in ie9. but in ie8, look fine

Comment: I'm also struggling to make shrunk images (png logos) look good in IE10 / IE11. They looks well great in chrome, but not IE. Was also fruitlessly trying to find alternative -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic